# Как сделать похожую таблицу в Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Я новичок в Qt. Как сделать похожую таблицу в Qt? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: наверное надо в `data()` вашей модели возвращать `QPixmap` на `Qt::DecorationRole`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как пример, можно просто унаследовать свою модель от `QAbstractTableModel`.

**testtablemodel.h**:

```
#pragma once
#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <QPixmap>

class TestTableModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    struct TestData {
        QPixmap pixmap;
        QString name;
        QString desc;
        bool checked;
    };
    explicit TestTableModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;

    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex& index) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    bool setData(const QModelIndex& index, const QVariant& value, int role) override;

    void initTestData();

private:
    QStringList headers;
    QList<TestData> rows;
};
```

**testtablemodel.cpp**:

```
#include "testtablemodel.h"

TestTableModel::TestTableModel(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractTableModel(parent)
{
    headers << "Name" << "Description";
    initTestData();
}

QVariant TestTableModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
    if(orientation == Qt::Horizontal && role == Qt::DisplayRole && section < headers.size()) {
        return headers.at(section);
    }
    return {};
}

int TestTableModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (parent.isValid()) return 0;
    return rows.size();
}

int TestTableModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (parent.isValid()) return 0;
    return headers.size();
}

QVariant TestTableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    auto row = rows.at(index.row());
    if(role == Qt::DisplayRole || role == Qt::EditRole ) {
        switch (index.column()) {
            case 0: return row.name;
            case 1: return row.desc;
        }
    }
    if(role == Qt::CheckStateRole && index.column() == 0 ) return row.checked;
    if(role == Qt::DecorationRole && index.column() == 0 ) return row.pixmap;

    return QVariant();
}

void TestTableModel::initTestData()
{
    for(int i=1;i<3;++i) {
        TestData td;
        td.name = QString("Name #%1").arg(i);
        td.desc = QString("Desc #%1").arg(i);
        td.checked = false;
        td.pixmap = QPixmap(QString(":/images/rsrc/%1.PNG").arg(i));
        rows.append(std::move(td));
    }
}

bool TestTableModel::setData(const QModelIndex& index, const QVariant&, int role)
{
    if(!index.isValid()) return false;
    if(role == Qt::CheckStateRole) {
        rows[index.row()].checked = (!rows[index.row()].checked);
    }
    return true;
}

Qt::ItemFlags TestTableModel::flags(const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    return QAbstractTableModel::flags(index) | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable;
}
```

То есть достаточно переопределить `Qt::DecorationRole` и `Qt::CheckStateRole` для вывода картинки и комбобокса в первой колонке. 
Чтобы состояние комбобокса могло меняться необходимо добавить флаг, что `Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable` и соответствующую логику в `setData`.

После, модель можно просто добавить для таблицы, через `setModel`:
    auto model = new TestTableModel(this);
    auto table = ui->tableView;

```
table->setModel(model);
table->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
table->setSelectionMode(QTableView::ExtendedSelection);
table->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
table->verticalHeader()->setVisible(false);
table->verticalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Fixed);
table->verticalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(80);
```

Установка фона и цвета выделения, а также шрифтов и других параметров возможна через css-подобный синтаксис в `setStyleSheet`:

```
table->setStyleSheet("QTableView { "
                         "    font: 14px; "
                         "    background: #404142; "
                         "    border: 1px solid #282923; "
                         "} "
                         " "
                         "QTableView::item { "
                         "    background: transparent; "
                         "    color: white;"
                         "} "
                         " "
                         "QTableView::item:selected {  "
                         "  background: #FF9800;  "
                         "} ");
```

Если нужно сделать что-то сложнее, чем проста вставить картинку, то следует прочитать про делегаты в Qt.